# Automatically turn MIDI files into .wav or .mp3

Tags: audio, media-converter, midi

I'm searching a tool that can be used in Python or via the command line (preferably Windows but Linux would also be okay) that returns a .wav or .mp3 file for a MIDI file.

What is the best choice for this task?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: And what command line (or rather, which OS)?

Comment: @Undo: I'm okay with all Python versions.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [TiMidity++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/timidity/):

- free and open source
- CLI
- Linux and [Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/137865-can-not-install-timidity.html) (although it seems to be painful to make it work on Windows, but maybe things have improved since then)
- [can convert MIDI files into WAV files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/timidity#Convert_files): `timidity input.mid -Ow -o out.wav`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SoX - Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/):

- free and open source
- CLI
- cross-platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS X, etc.)
- can [convert MIDI file to WAV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19762063/395857): `sox -t raw -r 44100 -e signed -b 16 -c 1 raw_audio audio.wav`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**timidity + FFmpeg for MP3 output**

And for MP3 conversion you can put it together with timidity + ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt install timidity ffmpeg
timidity MIDI_sample.mid -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -y -f wav -i - MIDI_sample.mp3
```

**FluidSynth + FFmpeg**

```
fluidsynth -a alsa -T raw -F - /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2 MIDI_sample.mid |
  ffmpeg -f s32le -i - MIDI_sample.mp3
```

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, FluidSynth 2.1.1-2, timidity 2.14.0, and this MIDI file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MIDI_sample.mid

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295459/convert-midi-to-mp3

Answer (score 1):

You can use SoundKonverter, which relies on FluidSynth and Timidity++ MIDI engines (you can manually switch between them) for converting MIDI to any audio format (Wav, MP3, AAC, Opus, etc.)
https://github.com/dfaust/soundkonverter/wiki/Installing-soundKonverter